# Detect finger drag using Javascript on touch phones?

Tags: javascript, iphone, android

Is there a way to detect finger drags using Javascript on touch phones?  I'm currently using jQuery and the mousemove() method doesn't appear to work on my Andorid phone.

**EDIT:** I suppose I should clarify that this is for a web application.

**EDIT 2:** I found a duplicate of my question a few moments ago: [Detect a finger swipe through JavaScript on the iPhone and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264072/detect-a-finger-swipe-through-javascript-on-the-iphone-and-android).  Although, it does not have an accepted answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect a finger swipe through JavaScript on the iPhone and Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264072/detect-a-finger-swipe-through-javascript-on-the-iphone-and-android)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [analogous touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755505/how-to-recogized-touch-event-using-jquery-for-ipad-safari-browser-is-it-possible): `touchstart`, `touchmove`, `touchcancel`, and `touchend`.  To bind an event listener for one of these events, you'll have to use, for example `.bind('touchmove', ...)` instead of `.touchmove(...)`, because jQuery does not provide convenience methods.

Comment: Try one of the 11 libraries listed at http://www.queness.com/post/11755/11-multi-touch-and-touch-events-javascript-libraries

Answer (score 0):

You could use a touch library like https://github.com/dotmaster/Touchable-jQuery-Plugin

This is lightweight if paired with a lightweight dom abstraction library like the very-similar-to-jquery Zepto:
http://zeptojs.com/