# javascript detect finger moved over a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've gone through the suggested threads but appears this has not been posted before. The closest one is this but it requires to know the coordinates: [Detect finger drag using Javascript on touch phones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287439/detect-finger-drag-using-javascript-on-touch-phones)

Suppose I have 3 `<div style='float: left'></div>` pairs:

```
<div id='Adiv' style='float: left'>A</div>
<div id='Bdiv' style='float: left'>B</div>
<div id='Cdiv' style='float: left'>C</div>
```

Instead of an onClick event on the divs, I want to detect how the user interacts with the buttons.

For example, if the user places a finger on A, then drags to B then drags to C, I want to output : ABC

And if the user places a finger on B, then drags to A then drags to C without lifting, I want to output : BABC.

Basically I would like to detect if a finger has moved/swiped his finger over a DIV then I would like to know it. Is this even possible?

Thanks for your guidance.

p/s This is for the mobile web browser, btw.
Best,

Answer (score 4):

It's a little bit tricky because you have no `touchover` event or similar.

So the solution is to detect the "touchover" by the elements "coords".

1. Wrap them with div (for example) and listen to him `touchmove` event.
2. Store the "coords" of the children (performance).
3. When `touchmove` on wrapper, get the `x,y` values from the event.
4. Check who from the children is in those values.

**Now, to the code**

```js
// first - store the coords of all the cells for the position check
var matrix = $('.wrapper div').map(function() {
  var e = $(this),
      o = e.offset(),
      w = e.width(),
      h = e.height();

  return {
    top: o.top,
    left: o.left,
    right: o.left + w,
    bottom: o.top + h,
    e: e
  }
}).get();

var currentTarget = $(),
    activeTarget = $();


var touchF = function(e) {
  var touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0];
  currentTarget = getCurrent(
    {
      clientX: touch.clientX,
      clientY: touch.clientY
    }
  );

  // if the touch is in one of the cells and it's disfferent than the last touch cell
  if (currentTarget && currentTarget != activeTarget) {
    activeTarget = currentTarget;
    console.log(currentTarget.html());
    $('#output').append(currentTarget.html() + ' ');
  }
} 

$('.wrapper').bind({
  touchstart: touchF,
  touchmove: touchF
});

function getCurrent(touch) {
  // check if the touch coords are in the position of one of the cells and which one
  var a = matrix.filter(function(obj) {
    var b = (
      touch.clientX > obj.left &&
      touch.clientX < obj.right &&
      touch.clientY < obj.bottom &&
      touch.clientY > obj.top
    );

    return b;
  });

  return a.length > 0 ? a[0].e : null;
}
```

```css
.wrapper:after {
  content:" ";
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}

.wrapper div {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id='Adiv' style='float: left'>A</div>
  <div id='Bdiv' style='float: left'>B</div>
  <div id='Cdiv' style='float: left'>C</div>
</div>
<hr />
<div id="output"></div>
```

http://jsbin.com/kokoxuwebi/edit?html,css,js

Comment: Thank you, it seems ti doesn't work in a desktop browser? I changed the console.log to window.alert() for now but nothing is popping up?

Comment: Of course it doesn't. You need to run different code for desktop and mobile. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Oh okay, I didn't know that. But I intended for it to run it on a mobile anyway, so don't worry about the desktop version. Thanks =)

I did push it up on the web to test it with my mobile browser, I could not see what was happening because I couldn't open a console window on the mobile to see if its working. I needed to see the response, should I open a <input type=text> field to see if its logging? Right now it doesn't seem as if anything is happening and I wondered if I did it wrong.

I made 3 files, the html, css and js. I put <script src> to the js and <link rel=Stylesheet to the css.

Comment: I was updated my answer so now you can see the `console` output on the screen.

Comment: Thank you for all your effort, but it doesn't quite work, I can tap the A B C divs but if I swipe over them nothing is outputted.

Please view:
www.nusantara.com.my/matsMate/swipe.html , www.nusantara.com.my/matsMate/swipe.js , www.nusantara.com.my/matsMate/swipe.css

Comment: GREAT! Thanks! Worked on Chrome for Android and Windows (desktop). Spent hours looking for something like this!