# Leafing html pages with flick

Tags: javascript, android, mobile

Say I have a list of pages. User can navigate it using "prev" and "next" hyperlinks. But there is much more ergonomic way to do this in android apps. You just flick left or right and see the next page. Is there any implementation of this effect with javascript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264072/detect-a-finger-swipe-through-javascript-on-the-iphone-and-android : Possible duplicate? Also, will definitely answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Related but not duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android, this implementation is a [Viewpager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html). Here is a [link](http://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library) to an implementation in javascript which works on my Android web browser detailing the flick left or right you so desire.