# Can we recognise UIGesture in cordova (native gesture to reveal native side menu in cordova )

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm working on a iOS project in which I want to use native side menu in cordova application. Is there any way to reveal side menu using native swipe gesture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIWebView` is already using the `UIGestureRecognizers`, so you have to add this code to the class where you add the gesture recognizer

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES
}
```

As Stefan said, is easier/better to use a javascript swipe that shows/hides the native menu

Or you can use the native [UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer_class/index.html), as it won't have any problem with existing `UIWebView`  `UIGestureRecognizers`

Comment: It worked for me .Thanks.. Is there any way to call javascript function after selecting the sidemenu item??

Comment: You can execute javascript from the native class using [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"javascript code here"];

Comment: post some code, that works because I use it in a lot of projects

Comment: stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:  is working when i intercept fake url. But if i want to call javascript function without intercepting the url , its not working

Comment: As I told you before, share the code you are using, create a new questios with it. It works because I use it. You can execute javascript code directly or even execute javascript functions you have already loaded in your apps javascript

Comment: this is the link to my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319548/calling-javascript-function-from-native-code-ios

Answer (score 1):

UIWebView doesn't play well with gesture recognizers, so it may be hard to get a 'native' callback on the iOS side.

You can, however, [detect a swipe in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264072/detect-a-finger-swipe-through-javascript-on-the-iphone-and-android).

A cordova app will rarely look or feel like a native app. For some applications that's fine, but if you want native, go native!