# Calling Javascript function from native code (iOS)

Tags: javascript, objective-c, angularjs, cordova

[image: This is how my storyboard looks like]

This is my Story Board. I have used SWRevealViewController plugin for my side menu in cordova application.  Added "Main View Controller" as class reference to the Last view controller(having item in nav-bar) .

On swiping from left to right on my cordova view will reveal Sidemenu. On click I'm saving selected row value in

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // menuItems is an array using which I'm populating the sidemenu
    NSString *  str = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

I just want to pass this value to the javascript function.

Defined my javascript function in index.html

```
    <script >
    (function () {
     window.execute = function () {
     alert(" machi");
     var el = document.getElementById('search');
     var scope = angular.element(el).scope();
     scope.$apply(function() {
                  scope.execute();
                  });

     }
     })();
    </script>

    calling this function using
      NSString *jsCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"execute()"];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCommand];
```

Comment: try with NSString *jsCommand = @"window.execute();"; When and where do you call the code that executes the javascript?

Comment: On swipe , sidemenu will be revealed, after selecting the row I wanted to call javascript function

Comment: tried "window.execute", even it is not working

Comment: when you say "I have used SWRevealViewController plugin", is there a cordova plugin for this? or you just tried to add SWRevealViewController to an existing cordova project?

Comment: I tried to add SWRevealViewController to an existing cordova project

Comment: @jcesarmobile, are you able to call javascript function ??

Comment: I'll try to put SWRevealViewController in a cordova project this afternoon and I'll let you know

Comment: I've been trying SWRevealViewController and I think your problem is the webview is on the front view controller and the didSelectRowAtIndexPath is in the rear view controller, so you can't execute the javascript from there. You have to provide more details or even a sample project if you want help, because it's not clear how did you used  SWRevealViewController

Comment: @jcesarmobile, I will create a sample project for your reference

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your native code to:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // menuItems is an array using which I'm populating the sidemenu
    NSString *  str = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *jsCommand = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"execute('%@')", str];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCommand];
}
```

And your javascript function declaration to:

```
 window.execute = function (str) {...}
```

You will find your passed value into **str** function parameter.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply, I know that i need to pass value, but I'm nat able to execute the function itself. I was checking whether function call can be made

Comment: Do you need to bind the function **execute** to the **window** object? maybe you can try first to use a more simple instance: `<script>function execute(str){ alert(str); }</script>` this is only for testing if there are some other problems.

Comment: tried without binding.. it didn't work,. that is the reason i changed it to window.execute()

Comment: Ok in this casa have you find some error in the log? i think that it must says something about the calling...