# Creating a slide up effect on a mobile device using CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

What I need to achieve is that when you swipe up the page from the arrows, the page needs to slide up and the user will be redirected to another page (as an intro).

[image: Intro]

I currently have a working way to use the slider:

[image: Swipe]

The question is: how do I actually make an effect that looks like the page goes up when the slider is used?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/)

```
var swipe = new Hammer.Swipe();
swipe.recognizeWith(swipeup);
```

See [swipe-recogniser](http://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-swipe/).

So once you recognise the swipe-up gesture, you can animate the `div` to `translate` up using css.

```
div {
    -ms-transform: translate(50px,100px); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(50px,100px); /* Safari */
    transform: translate(50px,100px);
}
```

Refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp)

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to do it. As I prefer to do it without plugins (well except jQuery), here's my way to achieve this:

**1. Detect the Swipe**

This can be achieved with the "touchstart" and "touchend" events. If the touchstart event is fired, you'll get the coordinates of the touch position. When the touch ends, get it again and compare the distance.

There are many really helpful articles about this topic.

[here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents2.shtml) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264072/detect-a-finger-swipe-through-javascript-on-the-iphone-and-android) or just google "javascript swipe"

**2.Scroll down**

Can be done in many different ways, depends on what animation you want. Google for "smooth scrolling javascript". If you use jQuery, this might be the easiest way:

```
  function afterscrolling(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $( YOUR_ELEMENT ).offset().top
        }, 500);
        return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Made a Codepen http://codepen.io/keephacking/pen/RaYxpm

Used `jQuery touchSwipe` and `slideUp` in jquery for the effect
For more about TouchSwipe ,Check link below. 
https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin