# Swipe Left and Right events a button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

For a simple two buttons like those

```
<button id="right" type="button">SWIPE RIGHT</button>
<button id="left" type="button">SWIPE LEFT</button>
```

How can i use `JQuery` or `JavaScript` to trigger a click on a button `document.getElementById('#id').click();` When i swipe left or right.

And is that possible using `PHP`?

Comment: Side note: `document.getElementById('#id')` should be `document.getElementById('id')` without the # - the HTML should hold the # sign for the id.

Comment: Do you want to activate a swipe on button pressed? Otherwise, why swipe? Could you explain better?

Comment: @FFdeveloper For example to make a previous post or next post action, Just a normal swipe, No need for click to activate it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- #id as for any id is used for the element

Comment: @CaliburVictorious so you have to trigger the action of the next or previous button. You don't need any swipe if you use buttons to trigger actions.

Comment: For small-devices touch screens, The button would be so small, that clicking it would be a pain.

Comment: So you have to attach swipe on the page and on the swipe left or right trigger the desired action. Link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264072/detect-a-finger-swipe-through-javascript-on-the-iphone-and-android

Comment: @FFdeveloper Yes, Exactly like that.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is a mix of JS an jQuery. It should be either of the below:

```
// Native:
document.getElementById('id').click();

// jQuery:
$('#id').click();
```

> And is that possible using PHP?

No. PHP runs on the server and has no bearing on client events.

Comment: i just wrote #id to mention any id name i write for the element

Comment: I get that - the important point is that you don't need the `#` prefix when using `getElementById()`

Comment: i meant it as $.

Comment: I have no idea what you're saying...?

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the click event usiong the jQuery [`trigger`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function like this:

```js
$('#id').trigger('click');
```