# element.changedTouches[0] error undefined. Chrome bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

I'm trying to make a slide effect in chrome but I keep getting an error when ever I slide. Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
        $('.table.table-responsive.table-condensed tbody tr').on('touchstart', function (e) {
            touchsurface.innerHTML = ''
            var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]
            dist = 0
            startX = touchobj.pageX
            startY = touchobj.pageY
            startTime = new Date().getTime() // record time when finger first makes contact with surface
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }, false)
```

This is the error I get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined. This is on line: var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]

Comment: Just in case if you debug the jQuery event, with `console.log(e)` for instance, does it contains `targetTouches`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jQuery Event object does not have a `changedTouches` property.

> The following properties are also copied to the event object, though some of their values may be undefined depending on the event:
>
> altKey, bubbles, button, buttons, cancelable, char, charCode, clientX, clientY, ctrlKey, currentTarget, data, detail, eventPhase, key, keyCode, metaKey, offsetX, offsetY, originalTarget, pageX, pageY, relatedTarget, screenX, screenY, shiftKey, target, toElement, view, which

https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Use

```
e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0]
```