# How to detect swipe in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make simple game in js. But for that I want to user play by swiping finger/cursor on the screen, up / down / right / left. There is a simple way to make that?

Comment: You could consider a library such as [HammerJS](https://hammerjs.github.io/)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can try this. Very simple and easy to understand.

```
  var container = document.querySelector("CLASS OR ID FOR WHERE YOU WANT TO DETECT SWIPE");

  container.addEventListener("touchstart", startTouch, false);
  container.addEventListener("touchmove", moveTouch, false);

  // Swipe Up / Down / Left / Right
  var initialX = null;
  var initialY = null;

  function startTouch(e) {
    initialX = e.touches[0].clientX;
    initialY = e.touches[0].clientY;
  };

  function moveTouch(e) {
    if (initialX === null) {
      return;
    }

    if (initialY === null) {
      return;
    }

    var currentX = e.touches[0].clientX;
    var currentY = e.touches[0].clientY;

    var diffX = initialX - currentX;
    var diffY = initialY - currentY;

    if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
      // sliding horizontally
      if (diffX > 0) {
        // swiped left
        console.log("swiped left");
      } else {
        // swiped right
        console.log("swiped right");
      }  
    } else {
      // sliding vertically
      if (diffY > 0) {
        // swiped up
        console.log("swiped up");
      } else {
        // swiped down
        console.log("swiped down");
      }  
    }

    initialX = null;
    initialY = null;

    e.preventDefault();
  };
```

Reference: 
https://www.kirupa.com/html5/detecting_touch_swipe_gestures.htm

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks!, will do

Comment: Wow Man! You are awesome! Thank you!

Comment: 2022, and still working

Comment: It is better to set up 3 event listeners : 

`  container.addEventListener("touchend", endTouch, false);`

` var initialX = null;`
` var initialY = null;`
` var currentX = null;`
` var currentY = null;`
` function startTouch(e) {`
`    (unchanged)`
` };`
` function moveTouch(e) {`
`   currentX = e.touches[0].clientX;`
`   currentY = e.touches[0].clientY;`
` }`
` function endTouch(e) {`
`   if (initialX === null || initialY===null) {`
`     return;`
`   }`
`   var diffX = initialX - currentX;`
`   var diffY = initialY - currentY;`
`   if (Math.abs(diffX) > ...`

Comment: @eosphere could You elaborate into possible answer?

Comment: @Piotr :  In fact, after reading the other thread "Detect a finger swipe through JavaScript on the iPhone and Android", the solution proposed is more elegant than this one.

Comment: @eosphere Ah, ok I found it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264072/detect-a-finger-swipe-through-javascript-on-the-iphone-and-android it is a lot of read and not too many answers use touchEnd, but anyway thanks for sharing!