# How to slide up/down div on touch?

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle, slideup

I'm creating a website where I want a div box at bottom of the page which is just a little exposed with a title of what it has inside it like say 'More about this place' and that contains options like nearby places, ratings, reviews, etc but that is not exposed and is inside the div container..

I want that box to slide out from bottom to top when someone selects(holds) that and swipe up!

And hide again back to it position when someone swipes that down.

How can I achieve this with Js/jQuery, css, html? Please help me with the code or the working behind it!

Reference: Similar like the "Explore Nearby" box of Google Map App!

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a library such as [Hammer.JS](http://hammerjs.github.io/) or check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23230280/68655) if you don't want to depend on third-party solutions.