# How to capture swipe up and swipe down actions while using TalkBack for Android

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

Trying to use the material slider for Android, from the fragment or activity side, can we capture the scroll up or scroll down gesture coming from TalkBack?

Comment: Have a look at [this question and my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57514973/detect-swipe-left-and-right-on-page-level/57540137#57540137). I suspect that the answer for this question is of the same kind. I don't know enough Android to definitely confirm it.

Comment: Thanks for the link, as it's a different framework. It would be different :(