# How to randomize an image within a slidershow gallery with html, css, and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently the image slideshow gallery allows for the browsing of the image by clicking arrow buttons to view previous or the next picture.

[image]

Is there a way to make it so that a random image loads everytime the website is visit? Instead of always starting from page 1, the website will start from page 2 or 3 for example.

Here is the HTML, CSS, and javascript.

**HTML**

```
        <div class="slideshow-container">
          <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
          <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
            <img src="images/art/38.jpg" style="width: 75%" />
            <div class="text">1</div>
          </div>

          <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
            <img src="images/art/43.jpg" style="width: 75%" />
            <div class="text">2</div>
          </div>

          <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
            <img src="images/art/39.jpg" style="width: 75%" />
            <div class="text">3</div>
          </div>

          <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
          <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
          <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
        </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
      var slideIndex = 1;
      showSlides(slideIndex);

      // Next/previous controls
      function plusSlides(n) {
        showSlides((slideIndex += n));
      }

      // Thumbnail image controls
      function currentSlide(n) {
        showSlides((slideIndex = n));
      }

      function showSlides(n) {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
        if (n > slides.length) {
          slideIndex = 1;
        }
        if (n < 1) {
          slideIndex = slides.length;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
          slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
          dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
      }
```

**CSS**

```
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.prev {
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect a finger swipe through JavaScript on the iPhone and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264072/detect-a-finger-swipe-through-javascript-on-the-iphone-and-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
var slideIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * slides.length) + 1;
```

This assigns the variable `slideIndex` to a random integer between 1 and the number of slides. Note that you will have to put

```
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
```

before this in order for it to work.

Or you could just replace `slides.length` with the number of elements you have, but you will have to update this every time you add or remove an element.