# Angular swipe pages with native events and rxjs

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to swipe between pages in angular using native events and rxjs. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264072/detect-a-finger-swipe-through-javascript-on-the-iphone-and-android/56663695) and changed my code to work with rxjs:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  fromEvent<TouchEvent>(document, 'touchstart')
    .pipe(
      switchMap(() =>
        fromEvent<TouchEvent>(document, 'touchmove').pipe(
          takeUntil(fromEvent(document, 'touchend')),
          pairwise()
        )
      )
    )
    .subscribe(([touchstartEvent, touchendEvent]) => {
      const xDiff =
        touchstartEvent.touches[0].clientX - touchendEvent.touches[0].clientX;
      console.log(xDiff);

      if (Math.abs(xDiff) < 0.3 * document.body.clientWidth) {
        return;
      }

      if (xDiff > 0) {
        console.log('right swipe');
      } else {
        console.log('left swipe');
      }
    });
}
```

However my function in subscribe is called multiple times, which means my swipe is never executed because my treshhold `0.3 * document.body.clientWidth` is never met. For debugging I added the following code:

```
fromEvent(document, 'touchend').subscribe((e) => {
  console.log('test2');
});
```

Then my console output is something like this, showing `takeUntil` not working as expected:

```
test -24.941162109375
test -8
test -9.41180419921875
test -8.4705810546875
test -9.88232421875
test2
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately Michaels answer only works for mouse events, because the endtouch event doesn´t include clientX information.

Therefore I tweaked his answer:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  fromEvent<TouchEvent>(document, 'touchstart')
    .pipe(
      zipWith(
        fromEvent<TouchEvent>(document, 'touchend').pipe(
          withLatestFrom(fromEvent<TouchEvent>(document, 'touchmove'))
        )
      )
    )
    .subscribe(([touchstart, [_, touchmove]]) => {
      const xDiff =
        touchstart.touches[0].clientX - touchmove.touches[0].clientX;
      console.log(xDiff);
      if (Math.abs(xDiff) > 0.3 * document.body.clientWidth &&
          touchstart.timeStamp <= touchmove.timeStamp) {
        if (xDiff > 0) {
          console.log('right swipe');
        } else {
          console.log('left swipe');
        }
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: If this solves your issue, you could mark it as the answer. [Self answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) are encouraged in StackExchange.

Comment: @MichaelD Self answers are only possible after 48 hours, therefore I will mark it tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

Usage of the [`pairwise()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/pairwise) operator is wrong here. Based on your expected emission `[touchstartEvent, touchendEvent]`, the `pairwise()` isn't doing what you think it's doing. The actual values getting emitted are `[touchmove[0], touchmove[1]]`.

I'd propose the following

1. Use [`zipWith`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/zipWith) operator to merge `touchstart` and `touchend` and ignore the `touchmove` if it's value isn't required.
2. Using `return` inside the subscription callback to stop the further execution doesn't look elegant to me. You could instead flip the condition of the `if` statement.

```js
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  fromEvent<TouchEvent>(document, 'touchstart')
    .pipe(zipWith(fromEvent<TouchEvent>(document, 'touchend')))
    .subscribe({
      next: ([touchstartEvent, touchendEvent]) => {
        const xDiff = 
          touchstartEvent.touches[0].clientX - touchendEvent.touches[0].clientX;
        console.log(xDiff);
        if (Math.abs(xDiff) > 0.3 * document.body.clientWidth) {
          if (xDiff > 0) {
            console.log('right swipe');
          } else {
            console.log('left swipe');
          }
        }
      }
    });
}
```

Working example (touch events replaced with mouse events): [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-14qsrw?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately only works for mouse events, because the endtouch event doesn´t include clientX information. I fixed it below.